# using let keyword in linq to combine queries

Tags: c#, linq

I'm writing a query that returns a list of models that needs data from two tables and I'm hoping the `let` keyword can help me. I'm starting like this:

```
var TheListOfModels = 
                let Data1 = (from a in MyDC.Table1
                              where ....
                              select new ObjectThatContainsData1()
                              {

                              }).ToList()

                let Data2  = (from b in MyDC.Table2
                              where ....
                              select new ObjectThatContainsData2()
                              {

                              }).Tolist()                 

                select new ObjectThatContainsBothData()
                { 
                     SomeProp1 = from p in Data1
                                 select everything

                     SomeProp2 = from a in Data2
                                 select everything

                }).ToList()
```

I'm not too sure on how to proceed and write the final `select` statement that selects from the result of the 2 `let` clauses rather than directly from tables. Is the structure of the query I'm writing a good starting point or should I write it another way?

Thanks.

Edit per comment: table definitions

Table1 looks somewhat like this:

```
PeachID | UserID | HarvestDateTime | SomeOtherColumn
```

Table2 looks like that:

```
AppleID | UserID | HarvestDateTime | SomeOtherColumn
```

I'm looking to extract all the peaches and apples into a list of the `ObjectThatContainsBothData` and the where clause is basically there to filter the `HarvestDateTime` and the `UserID`

Comment: It seems like a join is appropriate here. Maybe followed by some sort of aggregate operation. Can you provide the table definitions?

Comment: @ChaosPandion: I did the edit. I thought of using a join too but I didn't find anything to do the join on.

Comment: Do you need to group the output by UserID or HarvestDateTime? I suppose you could also reduce to a single object but your example tells me that you are looking to group the output by something.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: no, I'm not looking to group by anything. The dates are in UTC and I'm doing the grouping by day in the consumer and aggregating the data there because each user has a different timezone so I can't group by dates straight out of the database. Or so I assume.

Comment: @frenchie what is expected output? Can you explain what should be in second `ObjectThatContainsBothData` object in result list?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: in ObjectThatContainsBothData there should be 2 lists; one list that contains the Data1 and another list that contains the Data2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to apply Linq query syntax to ordinal C# code. Just create your object and execute two queries to get data fro both properties:

```
var result = new ObjectThatContainsBothData() 
             {
                 SomeProp1 = db.Peaches.Where(...).Select(...).ToList(),
                 SomeProp2 = db.Apples.Where(...).Select(...).ToList()  
             };
```

Comment: Ah cool!! Much cleaner since this avoids the let clause or the from clause. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Honestly this is what I had in mind but there was just a hint of doubt as to the intent of @frenchie.

Comment: Is there any site that can give the explanation of the internal working of the let? How it is executed and all...